# Mad Lib Project C++

Tags: c++, terminal

This is the instructions for my mad lib project

[image]

Below is my code for the project:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void getFileName(char fileName[]);
int readFile(char madLibStory[][32]);
void askQuestions(char prompt[], int count);
void getPunctuation(char punc[]);
void display (char madLibStory[][32], int numWords);
/**********************************************************************                                                
 * Add text here to describe what the function "main" does. Also don't forget                                          
 * to fill this out with meaningful text or YOU WILL LOSE POINTS.                                                      
 ***********************************************************************/
void getFileName(char fileName[])
{
   cout << "Please enter the filename of the Mad Lib: ";
   cin >> fileName;
}

/**********************************************************************                                                
 * Add text here to describe what the function "main" does. Also don't forget                                          
 * to fill this out with meaningful text or YOU WILL LOSE POINTS.                                                      
 ***********************************************************************/
int readFile(char madLibStory[][32])
{
   char fileName[256];
   getFileName(fileName);
   ifstream fin(fileName);
   if (fin.fail())
   {
      cout << "Error reading file: " << fileName << endl;
      return -1;
   }

   int count = 0;
   int numWords = 0;
while (numWords < 256 && fin >> madLibStory[numWords])
   {
      if (madLibStory[numWords][0] == '<' && isalpha(madLibStory[numWords][1]))
      {
         askQuestions(madLibStory[numWords], count);
         count++;
      }
      else if (madLibStory[numWords][0] == '<' && !isalpha(madLibStory[numWords][2]))
         getPunctuation(madLibStory[numWords]);
      numWords++;
   }

   fin.close();
   return numWords;
}

/**********************************************************************                            
 * Add text here to describe what the function "main" does. Also don't forget                      
 * to fill this out with meaningful text or YOU WILL LOSE POINTS.                                  
 ***********************************************************************/
void askQuestions(char text[], int count)
{
   cout << "\t" << (char)toupper(text[1]);

   for (int i = 2; text[i] != '>'; i++)
   {
      if (text[i] == '_')
         cout << " ";
      else
      {
         cout << (char)tolower(text[i]);
      }
   }

   cout << ": ";

   if (count == 0)
   {
      cin.ignore();
      cin.getline(text,256);
   }
   else if (count > 0)
      cin.getline(text,256);

   return;
}

/**********************************************************************                            
 * Add text here to describe what the function "main" does. Also don't forget                      
 * to fill this out with meaningful text or YOU WILL LOSE POINTS.                                  
 ***********************************************************************/
void getPunctuation(char punc[])
{
      switch (punc[1])
      {
         case '#':
            punc[0] = '\n';
            punc[1] = '\0';
            break;
         case '{':
            punc[0] = ' ';
            punc[1] = '\"';
            punc[2] = '\0';
            break;
         case '}':
            punc[0] = '\"';
            punc[1] = ' ';
            punc[2] = '\0';
            break;
         case '[':
            punc[0] = ' ';
            punc[1] = '\'';
            punc[2] = '\0';
            break;

         case ']':
            punc[0] = '\'';
            punc[1] = ' ';
            punc[2] = '\0';
            break;
      }
   return;
}

/**********************************************************************                            
 * Add text here to describe what the function "main" does. Also don't forget                      
 * to fill this out with meaningful text or YOU WILL LOSE POINTS.                                  
 ***********************************************************************/
void display (char madLibStory[][32], int numWords)
{
   cout << "\n";
   for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++)
   {
      if (madLibStory[i + 1][0] == '.' || madLibStory[i + 1][0] == ',' ||
          madLibStory[i][0] == '\n'|| madLibStory[i + 1][0] == '!' || madLibStory[i + 1][0] == '?'
          || madLibStory[i + 1][0] == '\"' || madLibStory[i + 1][0] == '\''
          || madLibStory[i][0] == '<' || madLibStory[i + 2][0] == '#' ||  madLibStory[i][0] == '>'\
)
         cout << madLibStory[i];
      else
         cout << madLibStory[i] << ' ';
   }
   return;
}

/**********************************************************************                            
 * Add text here to describe what the function "main" does. Also don't forget                      
 * to fill this out with meaningful text or YOU WILL LOSE POINTS.                                  
 ***********************************************************************/
int main()
{
   char madLibStory[256][32];
   int numWords;

   char yesOrNo;
   bool playAgain = true;

   while (playAgain)
   {
      numWords = readFile(madLibStory);
      display(madLibStory, numWords);
      cout << "\n";
      cout << "Do you want to play again (y/n)? ";
      cin >> yesOrNo;

      if (yesOrNo == 'n')
      {
         playAgain = false;
         cout << "Thank you for playing." << endl;
      }
      else if (yesOrNo == 'y')
         playAgain = true;

      else if (yesOrNo != 'y' || yesOrNo != 'n')
      {
         cout << "Invalid entry. Do you want to play again (y/n)? ";
         cin >> yesOrNo;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Any help with my code would be great thanks! Please try and explain so i know what exactly i did wrong! The comments above each function is not correct as well and i know that.

This is the errors I am having with my code. There is a space before the \n that isn't suppose to be there. Then as well at every " there is a random gap before and after it that I cant seem to get rid of.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just finished this project. And it looks as though you have everything correctly down, just missing some basic spacing errors. As you can see the errors are not lined up exactly with the expected. Just adding or removing some spaces, will let it pas with 0 errors.

Comment: You point the errors but don't explain where they are located in the code. Be more explanatory and give some examples of fixes.